# Time Capsule on Public Network

Tags: network, airport, time-capsule

I have an Apple Airport Time Capsule 3 TB that I want to connect to the ethernet network (not wi-fi) at my university so that several of my Macs can use it to backup to via Time Machine.

I am currently directly connected to the time capsule via an ethernet cable. So far I have disabled wi-fi and enabled bridge mode since the device will only be used over ethernet and will be obtaining an IP Address over the network via our university DHCP server, just as any normal PC would do.

Every device first needs to be registered with our IT department which simply involves sending them the device MAC Address, hostname, and owner. So, my questions are:

1. How do I obtain the Time Capsule MAC Address? I do not see it listed
   in AirPort Utility while connected to the capsule via an ethernet
   cable.
2. How do I configure the capsule so that only specific Macs can use it
       to backup to? There needs to be some type of authentication.
3. Should I connect the capsule to the network via its WAN port or its
       LAN port?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question, you hold control and option together and then double click on the Time Capsule in Airport Utility. On the summary page you will see a bunch of stuff, but under where it says "Version: XXXXX" you will see that it shows MAC addresses for all of the interfaces [image: this]

Secondly, the TC by default restricts backups to only computers that have the password which can be set under the disk tab
[image]

I don't really understand your third question, but if it means what I think it does, you should connect over the LAN port because while using the internet jack *does* work, I found it causes instability within the network.